# Is it an overfitting problem for SVM classification?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-extraction, image-preprocessing, gabor-filter

I am new in Machine learning, and I want to detect emotions from the face.

**Preprocessing:** I used equalizeHist to equalizes the histogram of grayscale images (JAFFE database with 213 images), in the goal to normalizes the brightness and increases the contrast of the image.

**Feature extraction:** I extract features with Gabors filters from images, and I get a matrix of 213x120. I split data: 60% train data and 40% test data, and I normalize it.

**Train and test:** for training the model, I use SVM classifier with an RBF kernel. With grid-search, I select the best couple C, gamma (using 10-fold cross-validation). Then, I test the performance of the model on the test data (unseen data), and I get 89% accuracy.

The problem is when I want to predict emotion from a new input face, **I get a false result.**. Is it an overfitting problem?

**UPDATE 1: feature extraction**

```py
gf = GaborFilter(ksize=(11, 11), freq_nbr=5, or_nbr=8, lambd=4, sigma=8, gamma=5, psi=5*np.pi/6) #Gabor filter with *cv2.getGaborKernel* 

data = []
for j in range(len(roi1_images)): # len(roi1_images) = 213
  vect1 = feature_extraction_roi_avr(roi1_images[j], gf.kernels) # feature vect from left eye
  vect2 = feature_extraction_roi_avr(roi2_images[j], gf.kernels) # feature vect from right eye (40 features)
  vect3 = feature_extraction_roi_avr(roi3_images[j], gf.kernels) # feature vect from mouth (40 features)
  vect = np.concatenate((vect1, vect2, vect3), axis=None) # feature vect of one face (40 features)
  data.append(vect)
data = np.array(data) # Data matrix (213, 120)
```

**UPDATE 2: Learn and test model**

```py
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=SVC(kernel='rbf'), param_grid=svm_parameters, cv=10, n_jobs=-1) # grid search with 10fold cross validation 
scaler = StandardScaler()
 
# Split data
X_train_, X_test_, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, data_labels, random_state=0, test_size=0.4, stratify=data_labels)

X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train) # Normalize train data
clf.fit(X_train, y_train) # fit SVM model
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test) # Normalize test data
score = clf.score(X_test, y_test) # calculate mean accuracy
print(score) # score accuracy = 0.8953488372093024
```

**UPDATE 3: predict new input**

```py
    landmarks, gs_image = detect_landmarks(path_image)
    roi1_image = extract_roi(gs_image, landmarks, 1) #extract region 1 (eye 1)
    roi2_image = extract_roi(gs_image, landmarks, 2) #extract region 2 (eye 2)
    roi3_image = extract_roi(gs_image, landmarks, 3) #extract region 3 (eye 3)
    vect1 = feature_extraction_roi_avr(roi1_image, gf.kernels)
    vect2 = feature_extraction_roi_avr(roi2_image, gf.kernels) 
    vect3 = feature_extraction_roi_avr(roi3_image, gf.kernels)
    vect = np.concatenate((vect1, vect2, vect3), axis=0)
    vect = np.reshape(vect, (1,-1))
    vect = scaler.transform(vect)
    class_ = clf.predict(vect)[0]
    print(class_,end=" ")
```

Comment: It could be. Or the test data's distribution you're using is not the same as the one new input faces come from. It might have something to do with your normalization process as well. It will be best if you could share some code so we could further help.

Comment: @GilPinsky Okey, I shared parts of my code. How can I know if the test data's distribution is not the same as the one new input faces?

Comment: Ok great. One possible way to determine that it comes from the same distribution is to use Inception Score (IS) which essentially measure the KL-divergence between two distributions. However, this requires many samples from both distributions. A simpler model could be to look for nearest neighbors within the train set and use the distance to the nearest neighbor as a similarity measurment (ie, approximate the distribution as a mixture of Gaussians). Having said that, it could be of more help if you provide the train/test loss over iterations plot.

Comment: But I am  dataset, how can I fit data to distribution? Any idea in Python ? @GilPinsky